# Laravel redirect Intended not working on Production

Tags: laravel, redirect, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The following handles the Redirect on my Laravel-Application after Authentication:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    //dd(redirect()->intended());
    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
        ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

This worked fine on my local machine, but not on the production server running Elastic Beanstalk.

The `dd()` in my code there shows the correct path on both environements, but on production it redirects to the url `/`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that because you use Amazon Servers which are load balanced.
The Load balancing works this way: The client uses HTTPS to connect to the Load balancing domain, but the load balancer itself forwards the requests in **HTTP** to the actual servers. This implies that the servers always see the requested URL as HTTP, never as HTTPS.

I drew a picture to explain my point further:
[image: Load Balancing HTTP explanation]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a helper function to get intended url from session as

```
function intendedUrl($default = null)
{
  $default = $default ?: route('pages.home');//default route
  return session()->pull('url.intended', $default);
}
```

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work on production, although it does on my local env...